# typo3 marking active languages

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I want to mark the actual active selected language.

What I want is to give the `<a>` element a class. Is that possible?

typoscript looks like this:

```
    ## Localization menu:
temp.langMenu = HMENU
    temp.langMenu.special = language
    temp.langMenu.special.value = 0,3,1
    temp.langMenu.1 = GMENU
    temp.langMenu.1.NO {
    XY = [5.w]+4, [5.h]+4
    transparentColor = #17353e
      backColor = #17353e
    5 = IMAGE
    5.file = fileadmin/bilder/DE-flag-32.png || fileadmin/bilder/US-flag-32.png || fileadmin/bilder/CN-flag-32.png

 }

    temp.langMenu.1.ACT < lib.langMenu.1.NO
    temp.langMenu.1.USERDEF1 < lib.langMenu.1.NO
    temp.langMenu.1.ACT.backColor = #000000


    temp.langMenu.1.USERDEF1 = 1
    temp.langMenu.1.USERDEF1.5.file = fileadmin/bilder/DE-flag-32.png || fileadmin/bilder/US-flag-32.png || fileadmin/bilder/CN-flag-32.png
    temp.langMenu.1.USERDEF1.noLink = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ACT < .NO
ACT {
  stdWrap.typolink.ATagParams = class="navLangAct"
}
```

Comment: the ACT section in the TMENU or GMENU is the current language

Comment: 1. "current" means "CUR" in HMENU, which means: active and all above. ACT means active. It's all about words ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

just try to be a soundboard, I was helped just by being questioned, I'm not that good with typo3 yet but could this work ?

```
## Localization menu:
temp.langMenu = HMENU
temp.langMenu {
    special = language
    special.value = 0,3,1
    1 = GMENU
    1 {
        NO = 1
        NO {
            XY = [5.w]+4, [5.h]+4
            transparentColor = #17353e
            backColor = #17353e
            5 = IMAGE
            5.file = fileadmin/bilder/DE-flag-32.png || fileadmin/bilder/US-flag-32.png || fileadmin/bilder/CN-flag-32.png
        }

        ## ACT < lib.langMenu.1.NO
        ACT < .NO
        ACT {
            backColor = #000000
            ## would this do the trick ?
            wrapItemAndSub = <span class="active">|</span>
        }

        ## USERDEF1 < lib.langMenu.1.NO
        USERDEF1 < .NO
        USERDEF1 {
            5.file = fileadmin/bilder/DE-flag-32.png || fileadmin/bilder/US-flag-32.png || fileadmin/bilder/CN-flag-32.png
            noLink = 1
        }
    }
}
```

(I do not know why or how to use this temp. rather than directly manipulate the lib, but that was not your question ... )